# Taking backup remotely using innobackupex

Tags: mysql, percona, innobackupex

I am trying to take backup from a remote machine using innobackupex.

```
./innobackupex --host=<mysql_server> --user=<username> <backup_dir>.
```

Its failing as it is unable to locate a directory in the server.

```
 (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

I am assuming it is searching for the directory in the local machine.
Please let me know how can we run the backup remotely ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you are confusing `innobackupex` with something like `mysqldump`. The former backs up the actual table files, while the latter connects to the database server and pulls the data.

Since it is [trying to backup the database files](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/innobackupex/how_innobackupex_works.html) it will of course need access to the filesystem on the database server, and can't be run remotely.

What you can do is [stream the contents of the backup to a remote machine](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/howtos/recipes_ibkx_stream.html):

```sh
innobackupex --stream=tar ./ | ssh user@desthost "cat - > /data/backups/backup.tar"
```

Or just save the resulting backup file onto a different server with the method of your choice (e.g. shared drive, `scp`, `rsync`)

Comment: I think we may use this option or might run the command using ssh and then copy the files to the remote machine

Answer (score 0):

I have the same needs, and I use `nfs` to solve it.

mysql on server A, and i want to backup to server B.

---

on server A mount server B's directory /data/mysql_data:
`[root@server_a ~]# mount -t nfs server_b:/data/mysql_data /mysql_data_server_b`
and then jest point the output to mysql_data_server_b;

---

nfs environment is needed: 
`yum install -y nfs-utils`